# Add Legend Entry for plot without any data

Tags: tikz-pgf

How may I render legend entries to appear despite having NaN data?
In the following example, only the HI legend entry appears. How can I get the BYE entry to appear as well?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.4, yscale=.4]
     \begin{axis}[
        width = 10 cm,
        height = 7 cm,
        label style={font=\huge},
        legend style={draw={none},font=\huge},
                legend entries={HI, BYE},
            legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}},
            legend cell align=left,        
            legend style={at={(0,1.2)},
            anchor=north west,
            legend columns=3,
           cells={align=left}},]

        \addplot[only marks, mark=square*, mark options={scale=1.8, fill=green}]
        coordinates{
    (0, 2.388854806)
        };

        \addplot[only marks, mark=diamond*, mark options={scale=1.8, fill=blue}]
        coordinates{ 
    (NaN,NaN)    };

      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a legend entry manually using `\addlegendimage{...}` with the desired style.

So in your case the following example should provide what you want.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.4, yscale=.4]
    \begin{axis}[
       width = 10 cm,
       height = 7 cm,
       label style={font=\huge},
       legend style={draw={none},font=\huge},
               legend entries={HI, BYE},
           legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}},
           legend cell align=left,        
           legend style={at={(0,1.2)},
           anchor=north west,
           legend columns=3,
          cells={align=left}},]

       \addplot[only marks, mark=square*, mark options={scale=1.8, fill=green}]
       coordinates{
   (0, 2.388854806)
       };

       \addplot[only marks, mark=diamond*, mark options={scale=1.8, fill=blue}]
       coordinates{ 
   (NaN,NaN)    };
       \addlegendimage{only marks, mark=diamond*, mark options={scale=1.8, fill=blue}}

     \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]